# How to handle rounding in uneven number bases?

Tags: number-theory

Is there any formal rule for handling rounding operations for the middle element in an uneven base? For example, in ternary {0,1,2}, what would I round a number ending in 1 to?

Comment: Consider for example the ternary number $11$. The difference between $11$ and $10$ is $11-10 = 1$, whereas the difference between $11$ and $20$ is $20 - 11 = 2$. Thus it would make sense to round *down* for a number ending in $1$.

Comment: Rounding is _easier_ in an odd base. $1$ rounds down unambiguously, $2$ rounds up (and $0$ doesn't need rounding).

Comment: It's not necessarily easier. One and a half is still ambiguous. And in an odd base, it requires dealing with repetends.

Comment: The current answers seem to ignore the impracticality of examining a potentially infinite number of digits in order to determine the direction of rounding. Sure, if you KNOW all the digits you are about to cut away, you can determine whether the value is above or below the midpoint (and apply some arbitrary choice if it is equal to the midpoint). But most often you DON'T know all the digits (because your numerical representation doesn't support repetends, or your values originate in the physical world where precision is finite), so rounding 1 down to 0 in base 3 could yield an error of 2.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to ask a similar question when I encountered yours. I've considered this quite a bit and come to realize that the rule for handling the middle element is up to the person doing the rounding, regardless of the base. But I think your understanding of "the middle element" is incorrect. Mine was, too. I'll explain.

In base ten, we're used to rounding to the nearest thousand pesos or tenth of a second or whatever. But ten is an arbitrary radix, so rounding to the nearest multiple of a power of that radix is also arbitrary.

If you're rounding to "the nearest multiple of one thousand", for example, the typical rule is to round down when $0$ through $4$ appears in the hundreds digit and round up for $5$ through $9$. That *seems* fair because each direction has an equal number of digits. But it's not! It's only fair if the $5$ is followed by another non-zero digit, however tiny that fraction might be. The actual midpoint ($500$) requires an uncomfortable compromise because the two closest multiples of $1000$ are equally near. So, at your discretion, you can apply different rounding techniques. In away-from-zero rounding, $500$ rounds up to $1000$. But in nearest-even-digit rounding, $500$ rounds down to $0$ while $1500$ rounds up to $2000$. This strives to minimize accumulated rounding errors by rounding half the midpoints up and half down. Away-from-zero achieves the same end if you're rounding both positive and negative numbers. The point is, this is a decision that depends on the application. And often, it's arbitrary.

By defining a round number as a multiple of a power of the radix, we *may* make our lives easy. But is that really the definition of a "round" number? If so, every integer is a round number if you only but change the radix!

On the contrary, I think a round number is whatever you've defined it to be. You can round to the nearest multiple of three. The comment by @froggie demonstrates this in base three, but it works even with decimals. $1$ rounds down to $0$, $2$ rounds up to $3$, $3$ stays $3$, and so on.

Herein lies where you went astray, and I did, too. The number one is not "the middle element", as you call it; one and a half is.

What happens with $1.5$? It rounds up to $3$ if you're doing away-from-zero rounding. If you look at this case in ternary, you've got $1.\overline{1}$, which, if you follow the same midpoint rule, rounds to $10$. (Doubling ternary $1.\overline{1}$ gives you $2.\overline{2}$, which equals $10$.)

So is there any formal rule? No, the decision lies with the person (or algorithm) doing the rounding.